# Requests.patch method (py library) works with https but not with http

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python 2.7 + requests & github3 libraries (modules) to find and replace some webhooks URL, in our Enterprise Github account. We have more than 500 organizations and 1000+ repositories (privates and publics).

Our python script works well for most test cases. However, I found an error, which I will explain below:

I have found some webhooks URL in our github enterprise account, that have the following struncture:

EXAMPLE:
http://10.10.10.10:8080/pr/XXXX-pr/v1/teamcity?buildType=BeCd_XXCDServer_Pr

I mean, that type of webhook URL has been around for a few years on our github, but since we will migrate some servers to the cloud, over time we will need to replace the host name in that URL. So, we created a python script to do it, which seems to work well.

The specific problem appears when the script attempts to replace the hostname in the URL that begins with "http".

If the URL starts with "https" the replacement process runs smoothly.

The error code I receive, is "422 Unprocessable Entity".

The URL that I send to the "requests.patch" command in JSON format, is something like this:

my_url = "http://MY_GITHUB_DOMAIN/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/hooks/001"

And the python code is:

---

```
data_json='{"config":{"url: http://NEW_GITHUB_DOMAIN/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/hooks/001"}}'
data_json_load=json.loads(data_json)
TOKEN="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
my_url = "http://MY_GITHUB_DOMAIN/repos/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/hooks/001"
requests.patch(url=my_url, data=json.dumps(data_json_load), auth=(username, TOKEN))
```

---

If I manually replace "http" with "https" in the original webhook in github (before executing the script) in this case the python code runs correctly.

What could be a root cause of this problem (The 422 error, when the script attempts to change a hostname in an URL that begin with http instead of https) ?

Could it be a bug of the requests python library ?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess this is a question for Github support since it's their server that returns an error when it shouldn't AFAICS.

Comment: Thanks ivan_pozdeev, good point.